# Upgrade to 4.0 Framework, then downgraded, now can't find Linq namespace?

Tags: linq, .net-4.0, upgrade

I just upgraded from VS2008 to VS2010.  In the process, I allowed it to upgrade my DLL's to 4.0.  I've decided that wasn't a good idea and now I've rolled back.

It all works fine in VS2010, but when it hits my CI server (CruiseControl.Net), I get an error of:

`The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?`

3.5 is on the server, and other projects that use 3.5 build fine, so I don't think it's a framework issue.

Anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do have a reference to System.Core, but it turned out for one of my projects, when I downgraded, it did not add this bit back into my project file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Core">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

The key part there being the RequiredTargetFramework.  I was clued into this because it wasn't only Linq that wasn't being found, but also Func<> and Extension method attributes.

It was all 3.5 stuff that was missing.

Comment: I've just done EXACTLY the same as you... Thanks for saving me some frustration!

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have a reference to System.Core.dll.

Comment: I've tried that :)  Specifically, when you do that, it tells you that you cannot add a reference to System.Core since it's included by default.

Comment: Is it there, in your list?  Is it set to the correct version?  If not, you'll need to hand-edit your project to correct it...

Comment: Giving you an upvote for being in the ballpark Reed :)  I saw your comment after I found the solution.